# Конкатенация нескольких строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Есть список строк, надо сшить все в одну. Например:

```
>>> string_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'eggs']
>>> ...
'foobareggs'
```

Есть ли в Python какой либо встроенный метод для этой задачи. 
Если нет, то как его реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У строки есть метод join

```
>>> string_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'eggs']
>>> ''.join(string_list)
'foobareggs'
```

Comment: можно ссылку дать на [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), где на этот и другие методы строк можно посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Если отсутствует/не знаком метод/функция - всегда можно реализовать велосипед
что-то вроде:

reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, string_list)

, но подобные вопросы легко будут решаться если вы пройдете - например основы на codeacademy - легкий, бесплатный и полезный курс